# Problems with Milestones, Entitlements and Apex Triggers

Tags: trigger, case, entitlements, casemilestone

I’m working on implementing Milestones and Entitlements into my company’s Salesforce Org for the first time. No one on my team has any experience with this feature, so I’m on my own as far as that goes. I’ve run into a problem when trying to implement an Apex Trigger to complete the Milestone, so that the user doesn’t have to manually mark the Milestone as completed.

When my trigger updates the Milestone, the Milestone shows that it is compliant, and completed, but it does not fire off the Milestone Success actions, so that makes the whole thing sort of pointless. I’ve put in multiple tickets with SalesForce support and spoken with my company’s account rep, but neither of these resources have proven to be of any help so far.

I’m using this trigger: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Auto-completion_Resolution_Time_Milestones_with_Triggers

And this class: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Case_Milestones_Utilities_Class
Any insight anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once the trigger updates the milestone, and you see that the actions are not created, are you able to click Edit on the milestone > save... and look for the actions?  Basically can you confirm that the action can be created manually on that very same one -- after the fact?  If not then it's likely not a trigger code issue.  If so, then it could be.

Comment: The actiosn do not complete if I edit the Milestone and re-save it.  However, if the first time the Milestone is completed, if I complete it manually, the actions do trigger.

Comment: Can you also post the actions definitions?  The entry criteria and action. Also, you should get the log from the developer console when the trigger runs... you would want to look for key terms like WORKFLOW and it would say something like EVAL with an outcome.  In the log you can tell if the workflow rule is even attempting to run.